# How to open a xterm terminal in a SSH connection with a remote Ubuntu without GUI

Tags: linux, pycharm, x11, mininet, x11-forwarding

I am using Mininet on a remote Ubuntu without GUI. And I am trying to use "xterm h1" to open a terminal on a virtual host in Mininet. But it showed me always there is no display connected. I am trying to use other X application like firefox and it showed me
"No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0.0"
Then I have set X11forward yes in sshd_config on the remote Ubuntu, and install Xlaunch on my windows but showed no changes.
Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?
PS. I am using a pycharm on Windows11 to establish this SSH session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running windows you will first need an application that will run an X11 server on your windows, [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/), for example. You will then need to configure your ssh connection to use that xserver. Finally you want to setup the DISPLAY variable at your remote to be LOCAL_IP:0 where LOCAL_IP is the public IP of your machine.

Comment: Hey Misho, thanks very much for your reply. Now it worked when I start a ssh session via putty. But it still shows me "error : cannot connet to display" when I start a session with pycharm, which is really weird. I tried it with pycharm again on my local Ubuntu ( I have dual OS locally) and it always works. So the problem still exists with pycharm on my local windows

Comment: Not sure how you are opening the connection from pycharm but I'd suppose it does not enable X11 forwarding (the default) so you have to modify that.

Comment: Thank you,after modify the environment variable “ display” in pycharm， it works

Comment: Glad I could help, consider accepting the answer on the thread @Djarlo